# Using INSERT INTO SELECT and VALUES MYSQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After a lot of googling and running around the different questions in StackOverflow, I haven't really found a solution that solves my problem.

I need to insert data into a MySQL table from 2 tables and from a $_POST request.

I managed the info from the 2 tables that I needed, but I cannot seem to insert the $_POST variables.

Here is what I have right now

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_orders (order_item_id, order_item, order_quantity, order_user, order_name, order_address, order_phone) SELECT item_ID, item_name, item_quantity, user_name FROM $user_cart, user_main WHERE item_status = 'carted' and user_name = :user_name VALUES ($order_name, $order_address, $order_phone)");
$stmt->bindParam(":user_name", $_SESSION['login_user']);
$stmt->execute();
```

The server doesn't throw an error, it executes properly but no data is inserted.

The logic I'm following is that it's looking for more data after the SELECT statement to insert into the table for the open columns but it doesn't pick up the VALUES presented to it, probably due to bad syntax on my end.

**QUESTION: What would be the proper way to insert the required data from 2 tables and from the $_POST request using 1 prepared PDO statement?**

Comment: I see a `$_SESSION` array, not a `$_POST` here.

Comment: yea that works. The final 3 values in VALUES are the issue

Comment: Btw, `($order_name, $order_address, $order_phone)` any of those strings?

Comment: Why are you only partially preparing your statement? Every single variable that goes into your query should be prepared. It doesn't make sense to just do 1 of them

Comment: You should select all the fields you want to insert in the second select. You can do that using a `JOIN` or by adding placeholders for the values you want to inject in a prepared statement. So no loose `VALUES ...` at the end.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton when i started working on that statement I wanted everything to be right, so I set bindings and all, but after all the struggle I only want to get it to work, once it works then I am going to polish it so its all right. No point in putting effort in polishing code that is still in test and will probably get replaced soon :/

Comment: @jeroen Could you provide suggested code? Im not sure where to add the placeholders as far as proper syntax goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> The server doesn't throw an error, it executes properly but no data is
>   inserted.

How did you conclude this? Without error reporting and exception handling you can't be sure.

In my code are two `TODO` comments. Search them and follow the instructions.

Regarding using `VALUES` clause inside an `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement: it doesn't work. Actually you would receive a "MySQL syntax error" message.

You have to include the PHP values, e.g. the PHP variables `$order_name`, `$order_address` and `$order_phone`, as column identifiers in the `SELECT` part.

About the parameter markers used in an sql statement, this is what [php.net](http://php.net/) says on the [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-parameters) page about them - php.net doesn't specify this on the [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) page too, and I don't know why not:

> Note:
>   The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.
>   However, they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names), in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a SELECT statement, or to specify both operands of a binary operator such as the = equal sign.

At last, the code:

```
<?php

/*
 * ============================================================
 * Set error reporting level and display errors on screen.
 * Use it ONLY ON A DEVELOPMENT SYSTEM, NEVER ON PRODUCTION!
 * If you activate it on a live system, then the users will see
 * all the errors of your system. And you don't want this!
 * ============================================================
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {
    // Read needed variables.
    // TODO: Provide your values.
    $user_cart_table_name = 'user_cart_table_name';
    $user_name = 'user name value';
    $order_name = 'order name value';
    $order_address = 'order address value';
    $order_phone = 'order phone value';

    // Create a PDO instance as db connection.
    // TODO: Delete this and use your own connection. 
    //       But use the first two driver options that I defined here as
    //       the options on your connection.
    $conn = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8'
            , 'myuser'
            , 'mypass'
            , array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
            )
    );

    /*
     * The sql statement - it will be prepared.
     * 
     * Familiarize yourself with the sprintf() function.
     * It is your very good friend when building complex
     * sql statements.
     */
    $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO user_orders (
                        order_item_id,
                        order_item,
                        order_quantity,
                        order_user,
                        order_name,
                        order_address,
                        order_phone
                    ) 
                    SELECT 
                        item_ID,
                        item_name,
                        item_quantity,
                        user_name,
                        "%s",
                        "%s",
                        "%s" 
                    FROM 
                        %s,
                        user_main 
                    WHERE 
                        item_status = "carted" 
                        AND user_name = :user_name'
            , $order_name
            , $order_address
            , $order_phone
            , $user_cart_table_name
    );

    // Prepare the sql statement.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // Bind the input parameters to the prepared statement.
    $bound = $stmt->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // Execute the prepared statement.
    $executed = $stmt->execute();

    // Get the last insert id.
    $lastInsertId = $conn->lastInsertId();

    // Display last insert id.
    echo 'Record added with id ' . $lastInsertId;

    // Close connection.
    $conn = NULL;
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time, this must have been a big mess to deal with. Second - you killed me with the way you bound the parameters, getting a foreach to do it and this line of code means nothing to me

        $inputParameterName = is_int($key) ? ($key + 1) : (':' . ltrim($key, ':'));


Absolutely no idea what that does, in a good way.

I kind of get the data type of the input parameter part of the code and the rest of it really. 

Could you explain what happens in that line of code above?

PS: About to test if it actually runs so stay tuned for updates!

Comment: UPDATE: Nevermind it's a shorthand for an IF statement. Still tho why go through all the hassle of building such a complex foreach for just 1 value which is :username?

UPDATE 2 : Even after I done the ToDos The result is the same - no errors were thrown and no info in the DB table. I can see in the network tab of the inspector that the info is being sent as a POST request and everything else...

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov Hi. First things first, then: forget that loop for the binding, for the moment. I will explain it to you in the end. Now, take the sql statement and paste it into a mysql editor (like phpMyAdmin, Mysql Workbench, etc.). Then replace the "%s" placeholders and the ":user_name" with real values. Then run it and see if it works. I'm waiting a feedback from you.

Comment: yea you had another typo somewhere but I fixed it so I cant tell you where exactly.

 5 rows inserted. 
Inserted row id: 39 (Query took 0.0016 sec)

It runs if I plug it in directly to adminMySQL... hmm so something is wrong with our placeholders/variables?

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov I just reedited the answer. The code contains now the classical binding assignment and validation of the input parameter. I explained what I did in "EDIT 1" too. I also found, that the parameter name in the `$bindings` array was false: it should have been `':user_name'`, but it was `':username'`. I corrected that, too. But I'm very surprised though, that your system didn't react with an exception!

Comment: there was no exception because I found the missing underscore and edited before I executed the code :D

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov That's good news. So, let's solve the PHP mistery. Try now from PHP again, with the classical binding assignment that I put into the main code 5 minutes ago. Don't change anything in the sql statement in php.

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov You had eagle eyes, regarding the underscore! ;-) My bad, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154972/discussion-between-denislav-karagiozov-and-aendeerei).

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov No, no. The sql statement MUST be exactly how is now in the answer. So, no double quotes around the `:user_name`! Try it exactly like that, to begin with.

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov Hi. I reedited my answer. I deleted all validation codes from it. Why? Because only if you are setting `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` are they needed. Otherwise they are redundant, because exceptions are raised instead. Bye.